# Is it possible to set QTY of product by SKU in Amazon API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am thinking about listing some products on Amazon but I need to be able to access them and update their quantities by their SKU programmatically. Is this possible with Amazon API?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Amazon Marketplace. There is also an API offered.